# Different set of validators for AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior and form submission

Tags: ajax, validation, wicket

In Wicket, I have written a AjaxFeedbackComponent component that takes a regular form component (such as a TextField) and feedback field and provides validation with instant feedback as the user types.  I use it for user registration, for example, to validate the minimum password length, or a duplicate username etc (similar to the Twitter signup page).  For, I have registered a `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` with the form component and update the feedback field with the ajax request:

```
formComponent.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeyup") {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        target.add(AjaxFeedbackComponent.this.feedback);
        AjaxFeedbackComponent.this.onUpdate(target);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, RuntimeException e) {
        super.onError(target, e);
        target.add(AjaxFeedbackComponent.this.feedback);
    }
});
```

This works great, as expected.  However, for usability reasons I do not want some of the validators to be run within the Ajax form processing, but I only want to run them when the final form is submitted.  I'm aware of `IFormValidator`, which are not called during the `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` event processing, but it seems like a code smell to add validators to the form that actually are validators that concern single fields only and should be encapsulated in the respective from components, say within `UsernameRegistrationField`.

For example, if I set `formComponent.setRequired(true)`, and the user navigates through the form using TAB keys, the `onkeyup` event is fired before the user has even started typing a username -- and immediately the validator's `.Required` error message is shown.  This is a bit awkward for the user.  Therefore I'd like to be able to mark a field as required for the form processing, but skip the required validation in the ajax processing.  For some other reasons I also want to delay (some "costly") other validators to the final form processing.

So my question is:  How can I disable a validator on a form component within the `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` processing, but do not disable individual form component validation completely?  Or do I really have to do all the individual field's validation as a `IFormValidator`?  Or would this be a good fit for `setDefaultFormProcessing()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using non-Ajax form submits, your validators could do 'light' checks only, by checking the existence of an ART:

```
boolean light = RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestHandler.class) != null;
```

Otherwise your AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior could store a flag in the requestCycle's metaData, which allows your validator (or a validator wrapper) to check for a 'light' validation.

Comment: Thanks, the solution to store a flag in the requestCycle's metaData and perform "light" validation only in this case works great.

Comment: How did you store the flag? I always get null when using RequestCycle.get().getMetaData(KEY) in validate method.