# Wicket - Update model with ajax without validation

Tags: ajax, validation, wicket

I have a form with several checkboxes of the layout: "[*] Items of type A         (count: 2)". 
Each such checkbox has a link attached ("count: 2" in the above layout) that displays the number of items in the list attached to the corresponding checkbox. The link opens another form for adding items to the list.
If the user checks such a checkbox the link becomes enabled and she can add items. But if the checkbox is checked and no items are added an error must be shown when form is submitted.

I tried using AjaxCheckbox to enable/disable the link and it worked fine until i added a validator to the checkbox (to check the above condition).
The problem is: when ajax request is sent from the checkbox the validator is called and validation fails as there are no items in the list yet.

Is there a way in Wicket to have a validator on a component and only use it when submitting the form and not when sending ajax requests? In other words ajax that just updates the model.

I know I can use IFormValidator which is not called in AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior cycle, but then i would probably have to create as many of them as there are checkboxes on the form which i would like to avoid.

PS: Sorry for not providing a picture, my dev machine is in an isolated secured LAN and I can't just copy a file from there.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the code or snapshot of the UI? It will help the answerers get better details of your question.

Comment: sorry but I cannot do so due to security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an IFormValidator to your form, which will only be called when the whole form is submitted:

```
public class ItemsValidator extends AbstractFormValidator
{

  @Override
  public FormComponent<?>[] getDependentFormComponents()
  {
    return new FormComponent[]{checkbox};
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Form<?> form)
  {
    if (checkbox.getConvertedInput() && items.isEmpty())
    {
      error(checkbox);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work, but I would prefer to keep those checks inside the related component, not propagate them outside to the form. I have found [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23974530/6399437) where you suggest setting a flag in the request cycle to be used by validators. I think that solution should do.

Comment: Wrapping you checkbox in a FormComponentPanel would be another alternative - it can validate your checkbox/items combination during form submit.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand how FormComponentPanel can help with my ajax problem? Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: A FormComponentPanel takes part in Form processing, being able to reject a form submit as a FormValidator does it. Similar to IFormValidator, but without the need to add it to the form - thus allowing " to keep those checks inside the related component, not propagate them outside to the form"